# Weblogic 12c with Eclipse Luna RC3

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, weblogic

I am new to weblogic 12c server. previously i was using tomcat 6, jdk6 eclipse luna, and my project type is tomcat project.now in our company they migrated to weblogic 12c.
the problem is i used to start/stop tomcat like this by using sysdeo plugin.

[image]

After start i used to right click on project ->upload context->click.
it used to  deploy automatically to tomcat than in browser i can access that.

[image]

now how to achieve this in weblogic 12c.i googled and find out that if my project is **dynamic web project**  than i can add server instance of weblogic and can achieve the above by selecting runas server option.
[image]
but my project type is **tomcat project** structure.
so can any one help me with this. 
Update 
i found this [plugin](http://mywl.sourceforge.net/installation.html) but it works from weblogic 6 to weblogic 8.1 but not for weblogic 12c.

Answer (score 1):

you need to install the enterprise pack

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/eclipse/overview/weblogicservertools-161590.html

I would recommend also, to try netbeans 8
It has better integration with maven, weblogic etc

Comment: it says i need to change the tomcat project type to dynamic web project.i can not change the structure of my project now. i have to do with existing structure only.

Comment: if its a web project, produces war file, then its supported, keep it mind though, weblogic 12c uses jdk 7 and not 8

Comment: project properties - targeted runtime and properties - facets - control what your project type is, you can change it, but it would be tricky when you do it first time

Answer (score 0):

this post is little old but I wanna share that I found just and I guess it is related to this post, there is no config combination exists between Jdk 1.6 + Eclipse luna + Oracle Service pack(12c) for Eclipse! You will have to upgrade or downgrade at least one of them...